# How to open an Electron application or open a browser tab/PWA app (focus on it, if already open) via a public URL?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, electron

I've been handed a feature where we're given public URLs which will contain some query parameters. Now, this URL should launch the concerned application (I'm the dev for the app) and consume those query parameters. The app has both versions, an Electron version and a web version. If the app is open, we just need to focus on the app. If the tab/PWA is open, we want to focus on the PWA.
Is there a way around this? I Googled a few things but couldn't find anything about this.